# how to make If statement and for loop work for an empty variable

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, undefined

My python script is called `dlimage`. I want to combine an if statement and a for loop. In the terminal I want to be able to type `python dlimage 1 2 3` and it would download only 1 image. Else if the variable of num3 is empty and I type `python dlimage 1 2` it would download 50  images by using the for loop `for num3 in range(01,50):`.

The error when I run `python dlimage 1 2`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dlimage.py", line 4, in <module>
    if not num3:
NameError: name 'num3' is undefined
```

How do I define it, since num3 is already in the parser and url below? Also I am not entirely sure my codes are correct. What's the problem here?

My code:

```
import urllib
import argparse

if not num3:
    for num3 in range(01,50):

        def download_web_image(url):
            IMAGE = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]
            urllib.urlretrieve(url, IMAGE)

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("num1")
        parser.add_argument("num2")
        parser.add_argument("num3")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        download_web_image("https://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}/{num3}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2=args.num2, num3=args.num3))

else:

    def download_web_image(url):
        IMAGE = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, IMAGE)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("num1")
    parser.add_argument("num2")
    parser.add_argument("num3")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    download_web_image("https://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}/{num3}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2=args.num2, num3=args.num3))
```

UPDATE: It is working now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The very first line that is executed in this program is `if not num3`. `num3` is not defined at this point. Hence the error. I'm really not sure what else you're expecting here.

Comment: set it's default value as some something, maybe `None`?

Comment: your parser-block `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()` untill `args = parser.parse_args()` has to be before calling the `if not num3:` and I think, instead of num3 it has to be something like `if not args.num3`. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't it be something like this?

```
import urllib
import argparse

def download_web_image(url):
    IMAGE = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, IMAGE)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("num1")
parser.add_argument("num2")
parser.add_argument("num3")
args = parser.parse_args()

num3 = args.num3

if not num3:
    for num3 in range(01,50):
        download_web_image("https://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}/{num3}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2=args.num2, num3=num3))
else:
    download_web_image("https://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}/{num3}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2=args.num2, num3=num3))
```

your complete code is (sorry) a mess.. first you have to define variables before using them. `num3` is not defined in your code, but you check, with `if not num3:`. And then you use `num3` as a variabe in a for-loop - doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about python before yesterday(i know, not a good excuse). I basically want to make a python version of the bash script I posted above.

Comment: updated my code, **without** debugging/testing. try it and try to fix the errors then yourself :)

Comment: the problem seem to be `error: too few arguments` now

Comment: this exception comes from `argparse`? try it with `parser.add_argument('num3', nargs='?', default=None)` (instead of `parser.add_argument("num3")`)

Comment: @JohnP. - If you have been using the language for less than a day, you should be reading tutorials and guides, not posting questions. The challenges you are facing can be answered with an absolute minimum of independent research. It is equivalent to asking a book club how a book ends because you simply haven't read it yet.

Comment: so check the url you're getting. Is i correct? maybe change from `if not num3` to `if num3 == None`. And you really have exactly format `.format(num1=args.num1, num2=args.num2, num3=num3))`  **num3=num3** not `num3=args.num3`

Comment: Matt and @TigerhawkT3, I also agree but in this case I have my own reasons that I won't go into. But thank you for the help, it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are using num 3 before ever defining it.
Second of all, you are redefining a function each time you go into a loop, and in your else block, which seems pointless (?)
Everything that is in your for loop that is the same as the else part should really be before if statement, except the call to download_web_image